# How should "pinisi" be pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

Yesterday, while searching the Internet for Indonesian sailing ships, I came across the Wikipedia article for the [pinisi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinisi). No pronunciation is given in that article, and I was unable to find anything in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suggestions/pinisi) or [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pinisi) or by Googling "pinisi pronunciation".

My guess would be that it is pronounced /pɪˈnisi/ or /pəˈnisi/, but I'd like to know for sure. **How should the word "pinisi" be pronounced in English?**

(Since this word appears to be used like an English word in the English Wikipedia article linked above, I believe that this question is on-topic for this site, but since I haven't yet been able to find its pronunciation in any English dictionaries, I could be mistaken.)

Comment: The French are ahead of us: [How to pronounce pinisi](https://www.howtopronounce.com/french/pinisi/)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are you sure that's the same word? No meaning is given, and as [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pinisi) shows, there may be other words that have the same spelling.

Comment: I'd say most people would pronounce it `"pɪnɪ'si"`, or "pinn-**iss**-ee" if you prefer.

Comment: I don't think most people would pronounce it at all. I don't think it's even achieved the status of loanword yet. It's merely a foreign word.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Is that how you've heard other people pronounce the word, or is it simply an educated guess? (Also, wouldn't the IPA be /pɪn'ɪsi/ instead of /pɪnɪ'si/?)

Comment: @MaxWilliams Which is it? /pɪnɪˈsi/ and _pinn-**iss**-ee_ have the stress on two different syllables… (My instinctive pronunciation was /ˈpɪnɨsi/, with the stress on the first syllable.)

Comment: No, but, like you, I've not come across more likely-looking references. I doubt it's in the OED, and this makes its inclusion in the English lexicon doubtful. You could contact Wikipedia.

Comment: "Per Horst Liebner, the correct term for the sharp-stern sailing craft is 'palari' or 'lamba' among the Konjo boat builders of South Sulawesi." *The Indonesian Pinisi* (http://www.kastenmarine.com/phinisi_history.htm). Both 'palari' and 'pajala' appear with attestation in the *OED*. 'Lamba', 'pinisi' and 'phinisi' do not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a foreign word.

Comment: I'm going to guess this was taken up by the Dutch East India Company, shared with Jack Tar, and became this in English: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinnace_(ship%27s_boat)

Comment: Or Indonesian got it from Dutch: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-rigged_pinnace

Comment: @SamEstep I'm afraid it's just an educated guess.  As far as i know there's no official recommended pronounciation.  Although, one could see if it's ever been pronounced by the BBC - they have a special department for pronounciation which one could take as the authority.

Comment: So we don't care how Honda is pronounced because it is foreign? Don't close, please. OP, you might try posting on [Boatdesign.net](http://www.boatdesign.net/forums/).

Answer (score 1):

It should be 'pee-nee-see' if you wanna use 'English' writing.  It's an Indonesian word, where /i/ is pronounced /ee/.